# Differentiator Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, laplace-transform

So I have a circuit like this:
[image: op-amp]

With the output equation as: \$ V_{out} = -(\frac{R_2}{R_1})\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{R_1C}} V_{in} \$

So the question is to derive the time-domain equation in terms of the input and also to show that the circuit performs the function of a differentiator.

So here's my work:
\[ V_{out} = -(\frac{R_2}{R_1})\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{R_1C}} V_{in} \]
\[ \mathcal{L^{-1}}(V_{out}) = -(R_2C)\mathcal{L^{-1}}(\frac{s}{sR_1C+1} V_{in}) \]
If we assume that \$R_1=0\$ then we have
\[ \mathcal{L^{-1}}(V_{out}) = -(R_2C)\mathcal{L^{-1}}(s V_{in}) \]
The \$sV_{in}\$ implies a differentiator since \$ \mathcal{L^{-1}}(s) = \delta'(t) \$

But I'm *pretty* sure that is either totally wrong or mostly wrong. Where am I going wrong on this derivation for the time-domain equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way to work this with R1 = 0 is to see that the time-domain current through the capacitor is just:

\$i_C = C \dfrac{dv_c}{dt} = C\dfrac{dv_{in}}{dt} \$

due to the virtual ground at pin 2 of the (ideal) op amp.

It follows that:

\$v_{out} = -R_2C\dfrac{dv_{in}}{dt} \$

Now, the circuit pictured is not a differentiator; it is a high-pass filter.  However, when the frequency is much lower than \$\frac{1}{R_1C} \$, the frequency-domain output is *approximately*:

\$V_{out} = -R_2CsV_{in} \$

But differentiation in the time domain is multiplication by *s* in the complex frequency domain.  So, the circuit is an *approximation* of a differentiator when the input frequencies of interest are much lower than \$\frac{1}{R_1C} \$.

Comment: A real op-amp will of course have a pole in it's open-loop response and this interacts with R2 & C to form a bandpass filter with very low damping & consequent ringing. R1 helps reduce this effect in practical circuits.